# How to design Aluminum Clad PCB panel - how is the panel separated after assembly

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

This might sound trivial, but I only have experience with standard PCBs. I need to design LED tube PCB and is only 20mm wide, so there will be at least 10 pieces next to each other on one panel.

My question is, how are these made to be separated? The tubes I took apart have all boards with smooth edges. The assembly house warned me, that it is not the same to separate these as it is with standard PCBs.

Maybe I will need a special equipment for this?

Comment: Talk to the PCB manufacturer.

Comment: Good one, of course! Still, being educated before hearing them gives me power to ask better questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have them milled and V-grooved in a similar way to the way it is done on FR4 PCBs.

The edges where they are separated from where the V-groove was will not be smooth, the other edges will be smooth.

If you require all the edges to be smooth you can have them milled out entirely and insert them into carriers for assembly.

Comment: Thank you, this pretty much sums it up nicely in a few sentences.